# Handling ArrayList out of bounds exception Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, exception

My program will be creating a two dimensional grid / ArrayList. It will search for all boxes around a specific box and return their elements. However if the box is at an edge it may not have any surrounding boxes in the grid. So we will try to access an empty slot in an arrayList, possibly slot -1.

Is there anyway I can write some code like this in Java:

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

//add 5 elements to arr

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){

    if(arr.get(i) is out of bounds){

        System.out.println("No elements here");

    else{

        System.out.println(arr.get(i));

    }
```

Comment: first of all, you can't declare an array list that way, and you can loop until i<list.size(), why would it go out of bounds???

Comment: Avoid using ***magic*** numbers. Period and end of story.

Comment: @SarthakMittal yes I felt it wasn't necessary to declare the data type for my problem. Also, can you read my comment below... is there an easier alternative that follows specifically what I asked for above?

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if i is outside the array bounds.

> if i >= arr.size();

Though a better solution would be to loop over the contents of the array with a for each loop like so:

```
for (Object i : arr){
     // Do something
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but I would have to write a lot of code that I was hoping I could avoid. Especially when I get to 3-dimensional arrays. Remember I will be checking values at indexes that could be less than i or larger than the array size, as it it relative to a specific box in the grid.

Comment: Ah, I see. Typically when I have been in situations with multidimensional arrays I have check the bounds by hand. Checking if you are outside your array.size() should work, and this way you don't have to have any unwanted exceptions.

Comment: @JohnDoe: what do you mean "I would have to write a lot of code that I was hoping to avoid"? How does this create more code for you? Your current code is dangerous. Bad code and AIOOBE trump all.

Comment: yeah i agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels i also didn't understood how would you have to write a lot of code?

Comment: For 2 dimensions wouldn't i need to use the conditions:

if i == 0 and j == 0, 
if i == 0 and j == size-1, 
if i == size-1 and j == 0, 
if i == size-1 and j == size-1

Answer (score 0):

You need boundary control check. For instance, if you need to loop around the neighbors of a point x, y, you could do

```
// assuming that you're checking around point x and y

// here you set minI, maxI
int minI = Math.max(0, x - 1);
int maxI = Math.min(listMax - 1, x + 1);

for (int i = minI; i <= maxI; i++) { 

   // here you set minJ and maxJ
   int minJ = Math.max(0, y - 1);
   int maxJ = Math.min(innerListMax - 1, y + 1); 

   for (int j = minJ; j <= maxJ; j++) {
       // do your stuff here
   }
}
```